# How to make first array the header and remaining arrays rows of objects

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and trying to get this problem right. I tried calling the index of the arrays but it prints out columns. Out dev environment is REPL.it, the virtual machine uses node v10.16.0 and help would be greatly appreciate

**Input**

```
tableData = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
]
```

**Desired Output**

```
output = [
    { first_name : "Elisabeth", last_name : "Gardenar", city: "Toledo", state : "OH" },
    { first_name : "Jamaal", last_name : "Du", city: "Sylvania", state : "OH" },
    { first_name : "Kathlyn", last_name : "Lavoie", city: "Maumee", state : "OH" }
]
```

**What I have tried so far is this:**

```
function convertTable(){
    var p=console.log;
    const [header,...rows] = tableData;
    var tableObj = new Object;
    var intermediateVal = [];
    var finalArr = [];
    for(var vals=0;vals<rows.length;vals++){
        var row = rows[vals]
        for (var key=0,val=0;key<header.length;key++,val++){
            tableObj[header[key]]=row[val]
        }
    p(tableObj)
  }
} 
convertTable(tableData)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a potential solution that uses array reduce.

```js
const tableData = [
  ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
];

const keys = tableData.shift();

const formatted = tableData.reduce((agg, arr) => {
  agg.push(arr.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
    obj[keys[index]] = item;
    return obj;
  }, {}));
  return agg;
}, [])

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: TL;DR :  Thank you, this is great work.
Acutal Comment: NICK!!!!!!! that is freaking amazing. I just find it hard to follow it. I am very new to programming. If my teacher compares my code to your code, they will know i cheated on the assignment.  I tried `Array.shift()` method on the rows. It did not occur to me to use it for the header. I was upset, "why can't i get the shift() to loop in the loop!!" Because it didn't make sense. However you are amazing.

Answer (score 6):

You're pretty close, but  you need to create a new object for each row of the result, and then push that object onto the `finalArr` array.

There's also no need for both `key` and `val` variables, since they're always the same.

```js
tableData = [
  ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
];

function convertTable() {
  var p = console.log;
  const [header, ...rows] = tableData;
  var finalArr = [];
  for (var vals = 0; vals < rows.length; vals++) {
    var row = rows[vals]
    var tableObj = {};
    for (var key = 0; key < header.length; key++) {
      tableObj[header[key]] = row[key]
    }
    finalArr.push(tableObj);
  }
  p(finalArr)

}
convertTable(tableData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage the reduce method which is included in arrays.

```
tableData = [
    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
];

const obj = tableData.reduce((acc, cv, index) => {
        acc.push({
            first_name: cv[0],
            last_name: cv[1],
            city: cv[2],
            state: cv[3]
        });
        return acc
},[]);

console.log(obj); 
// [ { first_name: 'Elisabeth',
//    last_name: 'Gardenar',
//    city: 'Toledo',
//    state: 'OH' },
//  { first_name: 'Jamaal',
//    last_name: 'Du',
//    city: 'Sylvania',
//    state: 'OH' },
//  { first_name: 'Kathlyn',
//   last_name: 'Lavoie',
//    city: 'Maumee',
//   state: 'OH' } ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however the Object Keys must be dynamic and not static. Otherwise I would use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Another functional approach

```js
const tableData = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
]

const [keys, ...values] = tableData

const obtainValues = (line) => {
    const [first_name, last_name, city, state] = line
    return {first_name, last_name, city, state}
}

const output = values.map(obtainValues)

console.log(output)
```

See [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/anh26738/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however the Object Keys must be dynamic and not static. Map kind of confuses me, I can't really get into it.